# Core Text Glyph Positions

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-graphics, core-text

I've been working on a view that uses Core Text and have been having a bit of trouble with glyph positions. What I am trying to do is overlay some paths of text over a UILabel but I am finding that everything is a bit off. Am I missing something with regards to the position compared to the label? Thanks!

Note: The green text is rendered with core graphics while the white is the label behind it.

[image]

```
func renderString(from text: String, shapeLayer :(CAShapeLayer) -> Void) -> ([CGPoint], [CAShapeLayer]) {
    var letterLayers :[CAShapeLayer] = []
    var letterPositions :[CGPoint] = []

    let runFont = CTFontCreateWithName(font.fontName as CFString?, font.pointSize, nil)//unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCTFontAttributeName).toOpaque()), to: CTFont.self)
    var alignment = CTTextAlignment.left
    let alignmentSetting = [CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .alignment, valueSize: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: alignment), value: &alignment)]
    let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, alignmentSetting.count)

    let attributedString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString(attributedString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), text as CFString!)
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attributedString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attributedString)), kCTFontAttributeName, runFont)
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attributedString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attributedString)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle)

    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString!)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)
    let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame)

    for index in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(lines) {
        var line = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, index), to: CTLine.self)

        line = CTLineCreateJustifiedLine(line, 0.0, Double(bounds.width))!

        var lineOrigin :CGPoint = CGPoint()
        CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(index, 1), &lineOrigin)

        var ascent :CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var descent :CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var leading :CGFloat = CGFloat()

        CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading)

        let lineHeight = ascent + descent + leading

        let runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line)

        for index in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(runArray) {
            let run = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, index), to: CTRun.self)

            var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: CGGlyph(), count: text.characters.count)
            var positions = [CGPoint](repeating: CGPoint(), count: text.characters.count)
            let range = CFRangeMake(0, 0)
            CTRunGetGlyphs(run, range, &glyphs)
            CTRunGetPositions(run, range, &positions)

            var glyphBoundingRects = [CGRect](repeating: CGRect(), count: text.characters.count)
            CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(runFont, .default, glyphs, &glyphBoundingRects, text.characters.count)

            for glyphIndex in 0..<glyphs.count {
                let glyph = glyphs[glyphIndex]
                let position = positions[glyphIndex]
                let glyphBounds :CGRect = glyphBoundingRects[glyphIndex]
               // let offset = CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, glyphIndex, nil)

                if let letter = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(runFont, glyph, nil) {
                    let letterLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                    letterLayer.path = letter

                    letterLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                    letterLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true
                    letterLayer.bounds = glyphBounds
                    let x = lineOrigin.x + position.x + glyphBounds.minX + glyphBounds.width / 2
                    let y = position.y + lineHeight - lineOrigin.y - letterLayer.bounds.height / 2

                    letterLayer.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                   // letterLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    letterLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

                    letterLayers.append(letterLayer)
                    letterPositions.append(position)

                    shapeLayer(letterLayer)
                } else {
                    print("Letter is nil.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (letterPositions, letterLayers)
}
```

Comment: Try initializing the label with the same attributed string that you use here. You probably set it with the `.text` property, and it probably has slightly different settings. Looking at it, I'd suspect that one is kerning while the other is not.

Comment: Same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Keep digging into kerning. UILabel sets things somewhat magically. As I recall, kerning is turned off by default. It's tricky to match exactly what UILabel does because it doesn't document its choices, but you need to make sure you've set every spacing attribute the same.